# How to Upload Image in Magento In My Controller

Tags: magento-1.9, image

How to Upload Image in Magento In My Controller

My Form.php

```
protected  function _prepareForm()
{
    if(Mage::registry('content_page')){
        $data = Mage::registry('content_page')->getData();
    } else {
        $data = array();
    }

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'      => 'edit_form',
        'action'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method'  => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multupart/form-data',
     ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('page_form', array(
        'legend' => Mage::helper('ailin_content')->__('Banner Information')
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('ailin_content')->__('Title'),
        'class'    => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name'     =>'title',
    ));


    $fieldset->addField('image','image', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('ailin_content')->__('Image'),
        'class'    => 'required-entry',
        'required' => false,
        'name'     => 'image',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('url','text', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('ailin_content')->__('Url'),
        'class'    => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name'     => 'url',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('description','text', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('ailin_content')->__('Description'),
        'class'    => '',
        'required' => false,
        'name'     => 'description',
    ));

    $form->setValues($data);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

My Function saveAction() in PageController.php

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()){
        $model = Mage::getModel('ailin_content/page');
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                $data[$key] = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getParam($key));
            }
        }

        if($id){
            $model->load($id);
        }

        $model->setData($data);

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
        try{
            if($id){
                $model->setId($id);
            }

            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['image']['image']);
            $data['image'] =$path. $_FILES['image']['image'];

            $model->save();
            if(!$model->getId()){
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('ailin_content')->__('Error saving Content'));
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('ailin_content')->__('Content Saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
            //save or save and continue
            if($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')){
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
            } else{
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }

        }catch(Exception $e){
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            if($model && $model->getId()){
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
            }else{
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('ailin_content')->__('No data found to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

And My Error in Grid view

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at the `enctype` attribute of your form, it looks to be misspelled `multupart` instead of  `mutipart` [image]